# Antarctic ice sheet melted and dumped into Atlantic ocean

Tags: science-based, apocalypse, alternate-earth

As part of an apocalypse in my backstory, the entire Antarctic ice sheet is torn from the bedrock and pulled through a portal, melting it and dumping all of the water into the centre of the Atlantic Ocean at about the latitude of the Strait of Gibraltar, roughly halfway between Europe/Africa and America.

This process takes place very quickly, at least the quickest time possible taken to pull millions of cubic kilometres of ice through a portal, melt it, and dump it from the sky - all in go. What would the effects of this be? Particularly interested in the effects on sea levels and global climate this would realistically cause due to the suddenness of the event.

Comment: Over what time span will this happen? Seconds? Days? Years? Moreover, the effects on sea levels and global climate do not depend on the point where you let the water free. So where is the difference with the "standard" greenhouse effect melting?

Comment: @L.Dutch I think it is the speed. Also some climate effects would be dependent on where the water is dumped.

Comment: Huge tsunamis wiping out much of the populations of the Americas and Europe would probably be the first effect? On the positive side, if enough people die upfront, the crop failures caused by climate effects won't cause famines.

Comment: The time span would be 'instantly', or at least the quickest time possible taken to pull millions of cubic kilometres of ice through a portal, melt it, and dump it from the sky - all in go. The difference would be the suddeness and the fact that it's all in one area at once.

Comment: A follow-up, considering the responses I've got to the original question. Would the effect be much the same if it was dropped into the Pacific rather than Atlantic Ocean (same latitude)? Or would the impact be majorly different in some way?

Comment: @Sesquip it really would not matter. Initial inland destruction from the tsunami may be less due to the larger ocean, but the overall effect will still be the same.

Comment: See https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions to elaborate on the generic “too broad” close reason.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding!  Suggest you start with the [tour].

Comment: Thanks. Read the questions link and tour link, still unsure as to how to adapt this question to not be too broad. Is it because it's difficult to give a  answer to without being very long-winded and also too difficult to actually make a definitive statement on what would happen? Feedback would be good, please.

Answer (score 3):

### Climate is hard

Firstly, it is hard to accurately predict the effects on climate an event has because all of the influences are coupled with one another. Changing one may not result in the behavior that is expected because all the other influences become affected too. The earth's climate is a self-regulating system change one thing and other things change to counteract it. This process does take time.

I'm going to assume that the water is dumped rapidly and that it comes out at average ocean temperature.

#### The Melting

[Antartica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctic_ice_sheet) contains 26.5 million cubic kilometers of water, which is over half the freshwater on earth. Melting all of it will result in a sea level change of ~60 meters. That's bad new all it's own, adding all of that water rapidly will cause catastrophic flooding. This [document](http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/es/papers/Coastal_Zone_Pop_Method.pdf) from the UN cites that about 40% of the worlds populating lives within 100 km (63 miles) of the ocean. While not true for the whole of the earth, but here in Texas a sea level rise of ~60 m moves the coast inland at least 150 km. So it's safe to assume that %50 of the world's population is at risk.

#### The pour

Adding the water quickly will cause a [mega tsunami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megatsunami) on a magnitude likely never before seen on earth. Every coastline on the Atlantic will be inundated by a wall of water hundreds of meters high that will wash inland for hundreds if not thousands of kilometers. Unlike a traditional tsunami who's open ocean height is a few centimeters this thing's wave will be enormous even in the open ocean literally like the [waves](https://youtu.be/4Hf_XkgE1d0?t=151) on Miller's planet in Interstellar. I find it unlikely that any sea-going vessel in the Atlantic would survive, submarines *might* fair better but I certainly would not want to be on one. All fixed platforms will be ripped from their foundations and the land surface of all coastlines will be blasted clean. Results will vary, but anyone that is not well up a mountainside or in the interor of a content will likely not make it, the casualties will be catastrophic.

#### Sloshing

It will take time for all of the water to distribute itself across the earth, during that time it will [slosh](https://www.sciencenewsforstudents.org/article/quakes-cause-faraway-sloshing) about. In some areas that will produce massive tsunamis and in others it will appear to drain the ocean. Given the volume of water and the amount of energy involved it may take weeks to stop. This effect will produce irregular patterns of destruction across the earth, spelling danger for places that may have otherwise escaped the sea level rise.

#### Now it gets bad

All that freshwater will wreak havoc on the ocean's ecosystems. I can't say for certain the salinity change, but it may be enough to kill off large amounts of marine life. Possibly enough to collapse the ecosystem. The change in sea level will kill every established coral reef on earth. In the aftermath, there may be a massive [algae bloom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algal_bloom) dues to the massive aeration, mixing, washing of nutrients from the land, and the stirring up of gigatons of ooze formed from the accumulation of [marine snow](http://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/marinesnow.html).

Relieving the pressure from the ice sheet will cause a rapid [rebound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-glacial_rebound) wich may contribute to overall global volcanic and seismic activity. All the fresh water disrupts the [Thermohaline Currents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermohaline_circulation), not to mention the sloshing. These currents are responsible for distributing heat across the planet (that's why Europe is [temperate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_Stream)), without them you may have triggered an ice age. This is a very real risk because no currents coupled with the algae bloom (wich pulls CO2 from the atmosphere) and the cessation of a significant fraction of human activity means the poles get colder. Less salty water freezes easier so the north pole at least will be enormous, even if it's ice sheet ended up in Siberia during the pour. More ice means reflecting more sunlight means cooler temperatures. This may cause an ice age or not. Hurricanes will be worse because the heat near the equator no longer ends up near the poles as easily, which equates to more fuel for them. These new found weather patterns will cause areas of extreme rain and areas of extreme drought.

**I would put my money on a cooling trend overall up to and including an Ice Age.**

#### Other things to consider

- Significant pollution of the water given all the industry that is near the oceans including but not limited to biological, nuclear and chemical.
- Slowing of Earth's rotation. Probably not significant, but enough to mess with GPS satellites. (If their infrastructure even exists)
- Global communication black out. The internet is gone. If not a total loss everything [overseas](https://www.pri.org/stories/2015-04-20/what-links-global-internet-wires-inside-tubes-no-bigger-garden-hose) is because all the connections are at the cost lines. Satellite infrastructure may be gone too meaning that [station keeping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_station-keeping) cannot occur.
- Power is out for most of the globe due to extreme damage to power grids.
- Radically different world map. Careful consideration of the setting in your story to make sure it does not end up under water.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exceptionally helpful. Regarding the communication blackout why would that, along the loss of the internet, occur? Simply because of the death toll and destruction in heavily populated coastal areas, or something else I haven't considered.

Comment: I ask because I'd like know your ideas about communication and infrastructure 15 years after the event, when the story takes place. For further clarification, this happens in October 2005 and is cocurrent with the shutting down of all electrical devices for about 30 minutes in England, Scotland, China, Korea, Japan, France, Germany, Belgium, and Luxembourg, with them resuming function as if nothing had happened afterward. The main story begins in June 2020.

Comment: @Sesquip one of my links shows the location of the major connection points for the internet. All of them are on the coast and subject to submersion or outright destruction. The scale of this destruction would be vast so major areas of the internet would be knocked out too like server farms and data centers. The widespread power failure would contribute too because the internet needs lots of energy. Other global communications are carried by satellites which need constant maintenance to function. Radio would still work, provided its infrastructure is intact.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'm sorry if I'm asking too much, but do you think communication infrastructure would be back up and running within 15 years, or still at a primitive level? Also, is there any event, simultaneous with or after the Antarctic/Atlantic portal (doesn't have to be within the realm of possibility) that would mostly counteract the cooling effect caused to such an extent not to completely stabilise the climate, but to prevent an Ice Age?

Comment: @Sesquip It's hard to say. Without a concerted and devoted effort, the global internet is still gone. Communications is limited to radio and satellites that still have the infrastructure. Likely military ones because their station keeping is redundant and resilient. Overall I still think widespread global communication would be limited. There may not be an ice age, possible but not guaranteed. Like I said climate is hard.

Comment: Wouldn't that huge mass of water displaced from the pole also sensibly alter the momentum of inertia of the entire planet and thus also the revolution on its axis of the planet?

Comment: @L.Dutch I do mention that it will slow the rotation of the Earth. I did not say much about the precession of the axis. I suspect that the water redistributing itself across the globe would limit the impact on the tilt of the earth.

Answer (score 2):

You're dumping a colossal mass of ice (hence probably triggering sizeable tsunamis).

Then, it is *cold*. The Gulf Stream would get disrupted, which means cooling down Europe considerably; it would be Little Ice Age all over again, with the Thames freezing thick enough to hold balls on it.

Moreover, melting ice becomes *freshwater*. This would probably wreak havoc with local ecosystems, killing off entire species of fish that cannot adapt to the difference in osmotic pressure, and further disrupt deep ocean recirculation patterns which are often driven by saline concentration gradients ([thermohaline currents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermohaline_circulation)).

Finally, ripping off such a mass off the Antarctic area would trigger a [post-glacial rebound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-glacial_rebound), with likely increase in [seismic activity and volcanism worldwide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr%E2%80%93Coulomb_theory).

All the above would strongly depend on the speed at which the operation takes place (except for the Mohr-Coulomb seismic activation, unless the operation time frame was in the hundreds of thousands of years. For *that*, one hour, one day, or one hundred years would probably change very little).

Also, depending on the portal's technology, the momentum of the antarctic ice is likely to be a lot less than that of the same ice dropped in the middle of the Atlantic ocean. You might even see skyscraper-sized ice blocks tumbling towards Africa, skipping over the waves at speeds in excess of Mach 1.

**update**: an ice block in Antarctica is sitting still, which means that it rotates around the planetary axis once every 24 hours. The axis is, say, 240 kilometers south of the ice block (with these numbers we don't take into account the Earth being round). In other words the ice block is traveling at a speed of some 2*PI*240/24 = ~62 kilometers per hour. The portal transports the ice block at a height of one kilometer from the surface of the Atlantic, at latitude 45 degrees North. The radius of the Earth being 6500 km and the cosine of 45 degrees being 0.707 make it so the block - [that has received no kinetic energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Witling) and is still traveling at 62 km/h in some direction - is above an ocean which is traveling at 2*PI*6500*0.707/24 = 1200 km/h. If the two vectors are co-oriented (best case) the block "sees" the Atlantic floating by at 1138 km/h westwards. The Atlantic and everybody else on Earth "sees" the block rushing in at 1138 km/h eastwards; at worst, it's 1262 km/h, or 350 m/s, where Mach 1 is some 340 m/s depending on air temperature.

Comment: The portal doesn't involve any kind of propulsion. On the Antarctic side, it's pulled enough to tear it off the rock. This propulsion ceases as it enters the portal, and then it falls from the sky on the other side, carried by gravity. Is that helpful?

Comment: Yes, I thought something of the kind. You'd still get an oblique rain of Mach 1 icebergs. I suppose they wouldn't roll very far, however - the middle of the Atlantic is pretty out of the way.